# Importing Comments with Datagrab

Tags: datagrab, xml

I've got an XML feed set up to import data from one EE install to another. I'm using Datagrab and everything is working correctly except that comments are not being imported.

When I look at the xml feed I can see the comments there and in the Datagrab control panel I've mapped the comment fields to their equivalent xml tags. However comments do not get imported.

Each time I do the import is fresh as I revert to an earlier database which has no entries and no comments in the channel I'm importing to.

Any thoughts?

EE 2.9.3
Datagrab 1.8.0

*****update*****

XML feed

```
<root>
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="200" disable="category_fields" status="not foo" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc"}
    <entry>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <url_title>{url_title}</url_title>
        <entry_id>{entry_id}</entry_id>
        <date>{entry_date}</date>
        <status>{status}</status>
        <blog-image>{if blog-image}{filedir_4}{exp:xml_encode}{blog-image}{file_name}{/blog-image}{/exp:xml_encode}{/if}</blog-image>
        <content><![CDATA[{entry}]]></content>

        {code_sample}
        <code_sample>
            <code>{exp:xml_encode}{code}{/exp:xml_encode}</code>
        </code_sample>
        {/code_sample}

        <seo>
             {exp:seo_lite entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        </seo>

        <comments>
            {embed="blog/_export_comments" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        </comments>

        <categories>
            {categories backspace="1"}{exp:xml_encode}{category_name}{/exp:xml_encode},{/categories}
        </categories>
    </entry>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</root>
```

FEED Embed:

```
{exp:comment:entries entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" limit="100" dynamic="no"}
    <comment>
        <comment_author>{name}</comment_author>

        <comment_author_email>{email}</comment_author_email>

        <comment_author_url>{url}</comment_author_url>

        <comment_date>{comment_date}</comment_date>

        <comment_body>{exp:xml_encode}{comment}{/exp:xml_encode}</comment_body>
    </comment>
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

I just ran the import again and it has 46 new entries, which is correct and showed now errors. However no comments were imported

Here is a screenshot of the comment settings in Datagrab
[image]

here is a screenshot of the xml feed showing comments  - it's a local copy of the site. [image]

Comment: Do you have a screen shot or something of saved import and a sample of the feed?

Comment: @OutofControl Have updated the post with screenshots and xml code

Comment: Just for clarification, on each test run, you are not 'updating' the entries, you are deleting them and re-importing, so they are new?

Comment: Should date be in the 2008-08-02 19:52:26 format, and not unix timestamp? I can't test here as I don't have Datagrab. However, most feeds use a date/time format.

Comment: @OutofControl yes, I dump delete the entries and reset before importing. Not it needs to be in unix and is importing entries correctly, just not comments